# What can potentially cause very high sync times during Safepoint operations with low or no spin and block times?

Tags: java, jvm

Safepoint operations in our JVM occasionally take very long to sync the threads. However the spin and block times are very low during these occurences. 
The common cause shows <100ms for spin but over 30seconds up to 4 minutes for sync.

Neither the Thread dumps on Safepointtimeout, nor an attempted log analysis of what is going on in those moments helped so far.

The system is a realtime RTP Streaming application using JMF (and JDK 1.7) on a Windows Server VM.

The JVM Flags used:

```
-server
-Xloggc:./Log/gc.log
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-Xmx2G
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics
–XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1
-XX:+SafepointTimeout
-XX:SafepointTimeoutDelay=20
```

The Logs for the Safepoints look as follows (including a few surrounding ones)

```
55577.063: RevokeBias                       [    2122          0              3    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0   
55577.066: BulkRevokeBias                   [    2126        168              4    ]      [    49     0 94867     2    13    ]  0   
55671.953: RevokeBias                       [    2111          1              0    ]      [     0     0    15     1    16    ]  0   



56867.883: RevokeBias                       [    1742          0              1    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0   
56868.738: RevokeBias                       [    1746        457              1    ]      [    88     0 39473     2     0    ]  0   
56908.219: RevokeBias                       [    1755          0              5    ]      [     0     0     0     1     0    ]  0
```

I would like to know what kind of circumstances could cause these massive sync times without being counted as spin or block times.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any thread which is too busy doing something else. e.g. flushing a file to disk can do this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is there any way of determining the offending thread? The safepointtimeout option is sadly not helpful, sometimes not even showing any threads at all.

Comment: `-XX:+SafepointTimeout` option already prints the threads that fail to stop after the given `SafepointTimeoutDelay`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25047229/3448419

Comment: @apangin Thank you for the link. Your answer in that question was the reason i started using the SafepointTimeoutDelay param. However it usually prints several hundred Threads, or in 2 peculiar cases none at all:
`# SafepointSynchronize::begin: Timeout detected:`
`# SafepointSynchronize::begin: Timed out while spinning to reach a safepoint.`
`# SafepointSynchronize::begin: Threads which did not reach the safepoint:`
`# SafepointSynchronize::begin: (End of list)`

Comment: @apangin
the safepoint log for this timeout:

`320166.625: RevokeBias                       [    1960          2              5    ]      [    29     3   112    41     5    ]  0`

states it is waiting for 5 threads to block

Comment: This means the problem is not in a particular thread(s) but rather because JVM process does not receive CPU time. Low OS memory is a usual source of such problems (swapping / transparent huge pages / direct reclaim).